# Web App Database Setup

Tags: python, sqlite, postgresql, heroku, flask-sqlalchemy

Firstly, I have searched Yahoo and haven't found a good answer.

All the Flask SQLAlchemy tutorials use SQLite, but from what I read SQLite isn't really good with Heroku - or at least a Yahoo search of SQLite Heroku - reveals many issues with it?

If there aren't in fact any issues with using SQLite, please let me know.

How do I set a database up with Postgres and FlaskSQLAlchemy - since from my research that is what Heroku supports?

Answer (score 1):

Using Flask-SQLAlchemy, you can just do this:

```
from flask import Flask
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'postgresql://username:password@host/dbname'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)
```

Now you can use this db object to do whatever you need.

Read here for more:
http://packages.python.org/Flask-SQLAlchemy/config.html#configuration-keys